# The controller must return a response

Tags: symfony

I am new with Symfony 2.. I try something really basic.. I have just created a bundle with the command line et put this in my controller :

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return new Response('<html><body>Hello '.$name.'!</body></html>');
    }
}
```

and I have a logicException with "the controler must return a response"

this is not what I am doing here ?

Thank u

PS : I add the routing.yml in app

```
acme_hello:
   resource: "@AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
   prefix:   /
```

routing.yml in Resources

```
acme_hello_homepage:
   pattern:  /hello/{name}
   defaults: { _controller: AcmeHelloBundle:Default:index }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the right route?

Comment: well obviously it arrives to the controller..so route is fine no ?

Comment: before I forgot to write the use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response;

Comment: and I had a php error saying that he does not know the Response object. So I am quite sure it goes to the controller

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The controller must return a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` instance, so you should have:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

instead of

```
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response;
```